# Setting custom internal storage requirement for application - android

Tags: android, installation, storage, customization

I'm developing an application that after the installation will download files depending on user needs.

Is there a way to set a custom ammount of internal storage an android application installation needs? (the max ammount of memory may require in the future, bigger than the actual apk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to set a custom ammount of internal storage an android application installation needs?

No. All apps have the same "max ammount of memory may require in the future, bigger than the actual apk", which is "the entirety of internal storage". There is no quota system in Android -- any app can use as much internal storage as it wishes, until internal storage runs out of room.